# Serious issue after deployment to server - random text on the page

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have migrated some website updates from staging to live, but now, when I view the live site, I get the following random text on the page:

This only appears after I log on, so I can get the logon page to appear.
I re uploaded the latest dlls from dev, to staging and then live, and now staging has the same issue. However, staging was previously working, and dev doesn't have the issue!

���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��Ey�')=��y6�����h���i�f���ӏ���o�'g�UU�O'/����i�\Vm:��j�/��6��ԸhӢI����X���w��i���I5�N�y�l�ϳEQ^?��'�z�-���ӫ������U��J��)~�?J�����*��Ѥ̦oI��]�P�"�/��v[����W�~���m`N�rvk���Mqz3���wV�vR��{_��IW�2����������,KO�eS��יy�/����m^+E eB��c*�j�w��,�Vu���Q����a�2��*����E�]�-/%��j�j�(��Y���{�ʖ�lR���n���,��ć�����2�����uC�   ԡO��w}V|W�L�d��\0��>��m���ւh�����=z��4���GV,ӏ�~��Ve1elǏ�uzU���g�;;�{�Y�lW���)Jz���]���a�w�>.�!a/�0�=���uB���4�������Q���pki��s}I?_����e��*�X�Y=J���uq�FH49J��ʹ.V�0��N����z� ) ���4���jJsi���by�����ͧk���?�&��U>I������/�ĩ��"��fMK욶5 ���N�G�<�P1�lR�[��'��I��y�T���X3k   �L����h����A��a=�۬(�����c����/*Oʂ��l�G�72�è���5Q�y�pG���1���?�g:ń�o�Ku�C��7b��@^�~�5��&����<'��g����EV���2�<�e%�j �މ� x1#��yA���i���$/�+�8;�Ș��B�v�Ga"S�^F� ����>&�8|���tk������݇;�w���>�1(hd������K��!;���IE�s_��[�ޝ��݇���=����ٲ��e��������΃ =��5/����ͼ��,�����Y�$�ݲM�I����Ox�-����4$����r���$�g�)���N4^, R����,��1��"3K�rF��ni�������_�U��ʛuپ�i��s�&���=ܻi����bY4�SV����A���ClY�y��*2��H���� @����l�D@�� :�k��]�KKV�4k��SB������7���n���j6J�N���L:J?����r"��)�/��O���z+����l�;,�|9{S�,V9�p�v�w�Ż�!�n>����̵x����.�v��P��-Ϋ-m�>m������7��*<�3���n�>9� f�f��߯   n>��[�

Comment: That's pretty wild.  What does the browser source look like?

Comment: It's the same! I think it only happens after I access the database, as logon page loads

Comment: trying a server reboot to see if that helps. Thankfully the site is on its own box

Comment: Can you show what the response HTTP headers are ...

Comment: seems that ur hosting space has virus,is ur app hosted on thrid party shared hosting ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, issue was due to me taking another database offline (even though this database is obsolete and not included in any connection strings.

Going to open a new question for that issue